Need suggestion for creating cart price rule Magento 2
I want to give an offer on these SKUS "sku-111-11-11,sku-222-22-22,sku-333-33-33,sku-444-44-44,sku-555-55-55,sku-666-66-66".
case 1: If customer add any 2, 4, 6 items from above skus then customer will get 50% discount.
case 2: If customer add any one sku with qty 2 then they will get 50% discount.
case 3: If customer add three skus from above skus then customer will get 50% off only on 2 items.(This one is the main where I am getting stuck right now)
So technically we want to give 1 - 1 sku free for above mentioned skus, how can I do this using cart price rule.

Default magento you have to manually add product and it will give you additional item with price zero,To achive you can create a customization for your requirment. You can the refer the files below.
Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Metadata\ValueProvider">
<plugin name="salesrule-plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Rule\Metadata\CustomValueProvider" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
</config>

Vendor/Module/Plugin/Rule/Metadata/CustomValueProvider.php
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Rule\Metadata;

class CustomValueProvider
{
    public function afterGetMetadataValues(
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Metadata\ValueProvider $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $applyOptions = [
            'label' => __('Free Gift'),
            'value' => [
                [
                    'label' => 'Buy x get x free',
                    'value' => 'buy-x-get-x-free',
                ]
                
            ],
        ];
        
        array_push($result['actions']['children']['simple_action']['arguments']['data']['config']['options'], $applyOptions); 
        return $result;
    }
}

Vendor/Module/etc/db_schema.xml
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
<table name="salesrule">
<column xsi:type="varchar" name="gift_skus" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Gift Sku"/>
<column xsi:type="int" name="giftsku_qty" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="false" default="0" comment="Gifts Qty Allowed"/>
</table>
</schema>

Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\CalculatorFactory">
<arguments>
<argument name="discountRules" xsi:type="array">
<item name="buy-x-get-x-free" xsi:type="string">\Vendor\Module\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\BuyXGetX</item>
</argument>
</arguments>
</type>
</config>

Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_rule_form.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="actions" sortOrder="30">
    <field name="custom_step_nqty" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sales_rule</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">4</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    <rule name="validate-number" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    <rule name="validate-zero-or-greater" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Discount Qty (Buy Y)</label>
                <dataScope>custom_step_nqty</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="gift_skus" formElement="textarea">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sales_rule</item>
                    <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enter products separated by comma. </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>number</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Promo SKU</label>
                <dataScope>promo_skus</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>

Vendor/Module/Model/Rule/Action/Discount/BuyXGetX.php
    <?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Rule\Action\Discount;
    
    use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\AbstractDiscount;
    use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\DataFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
    use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Validator;
    use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
    use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
    use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ItemFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
    use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
    use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
    
    class BuyXGetX extends AbstractDiscount
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\DataFactory
         */
        protected $discountFactory;
    
        /**
         * @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Validator
         */
        protected $validator;
    
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface
         */
        protected $priceCurrency;
    
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
         */
        protected $cart;
    
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
         */
        protected $product;
    
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
         */
        protected $session;
    
        /**
         * @var  ItemFactory
         */
        protected $itemFactory;
        /**
         * @var  Json
         */
        protected $serializer;
        
        /**
         * @var LoggerInterface
         */
        protected $logger;
    
        
        public function __construct(
            Validator $validator,
            DataFactory $discountDataFactory,
            PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
            Cart $cart,
            Product $product,
            Session $session,
            ItemFactory $itemFactory,
            Json $serializer = null,
            LoggerInterface $logger
        ) {
            $this->validator = $validator;
            $this->discountFactory = $discountDataFactory;
            $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
            $this->cart = $cart;
            $this->product = $product;
            $this->session = $session;
            $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
            $this->serializer = $serializer ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json::class); 
            $this->logger = $logger;
        }
    
        
        public function calculate($rule, $item, $qty)
        {
            $discountData = $this->discountFactory->create();
            $this->applyFreeGiftDiscount($item, $rule, $qty);
            
            return $discountData;
        }
    
        
        protected function applyFreeGiftDiscount($item, $rule, $qty)
        {     
        try {   
// add your logic here for simple product below is sample
            $quote = $item->getQuote();
                $productId = $item->getProductId();
                $ruleId =$rule->getId();
                $additionalOptions = []; // if you have any item custom option
                $product = $this->product->load($productId);
                $product->addCustomOption('additional_options', $this->serializer->serialize($additionalOptions));
                $product->setPrice(0);
                $product->setOriginalPrice(0);
                $product->setCustomPrice(0);
                $product->setOriginalCustomPrice(0);
                $buyRequest = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject([
                    'qty' => $qty,
                    'price' => '0',
                    'final_price' => '0'
                ]);
                $quote->addProduct($product, $buyRequest);
                
                } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                 $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
            }  
        }   
    }

Also there is a blog available that might help :
https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-cart-rule-for-buy-x-get-next-y-with-percent-discount-in-magento-2/
